# Increment (and Decrement) values in a [Google Sheet] column

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, increment, distinct-values, decrement

[image]

The image (attached) is a simple "AppScript" adapted from a popular YouTube ...that allows "Values" (in a column) to be increased by 1 - by clicking an "Arrow" (button) - that I've linked to the script

[image]

By Clicking the "Up" Arrow, all the values will change from 6 ...to 7 (ie: go "Up" by one value)

[image]

**QUESTION(s):**
How do I 'adjust' the Script to:

1. Assess (or Evaluate) the Values in the column
2. Ignore any values that are "Zero" (0)
3. Increment (by 1) ...all the other "Non-Zero" values

And finally, if a Value is 'different' than the other values (eg: 5 ...instead of 7)

4. Increment a value of 5 to 6 ...and the 'other' values of 7 to 8

[image]

Currently, the Script will change 5 to an 8 (along with all the 7's)

[image]

**I'd like the Script to change the 5 to a 6 (and the 7's can increment to 8's)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggestion:

You can have the script iterate through each of the value of the range and increment it if the value isn't equal to 0.

Do try this script:

```
function incrementA2A5() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:A5");
  var values = range.getValues();

  //The forEach loop below iterates through each value of the range.
  //If the value isn't equal to zero, the loop will increment it by one.

  values.forEach(x => x[0] != 0 ? x[0] += 1 : x[0]);

  range.setValues(values); //Sets the updated values on the range
}
```

.GIF demo of the script:
[image]

Comment: The Script works (like a charm) - Wow 

I'm only familiar Excel's < or > logic (algorithms) ...so, any advice on how:

    x[0] ...and
    !=0 ...and
    =1 : x[0] 

...works, would be greatly appreciated 

Thanks again for your help 

Comment: You're welcome! The statement you're referring to's utilizing Javascript's [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) The statement `x[0] != 0 ?` translates to **if x[0] is not equal to zero** The next part, `x[0] += 1`, adds 1 to the value if the `if` statement is true. `: x[0]` is essentially an `else` statement and means that the value is returned without any modification if the `if` statement is false. `x[0]` is just a placeholder referring to the first and, in the example, only value of the row being evaluated.

Comment: Follow-up ...re: adding multiple columns (or ranges) to increment.  I'd like to increase the values in Columns/Rows A2:A5 & C2:C5 & E2:E5